# Find $n$ such that $209$ divides $n^{180}-n^{20}-n^{36}+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Finding $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (with $n > 1$) such that $209$ divides $n^{180}-n^{20}-n^{36}+1$ is equivalent to solving $$ n^{180} - n^{20} - n^{36} + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 11 \quad \text{ and } \quad n^{180} - n^{20} - n^{36} + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 19. $$

Using *Fermat Little Theorem* one can further reduce the problem to $$ n^{6}    -1\equiv 0 \mod 11 \quad \text{ and } \quad  (n + 1)(n-1) \equiv 0 \mod 19$$

How does one solve this problem (specifically, $n^{6} -1  \equiv 0 \mod 11$) in a straightforward way?

Comment: Any restriction on $n$? Because $n=1$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^{6} \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ and $n^{10} \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ imply $n^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ because $\gcd(6,10)=2$.

So $n^{180}-n^{20}-n^{36}+1 \equiv 0\bmod 209$ is equivalent to $n^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod 209$, which is much easier to solve, giving $n=\pm 1, \pm 56$.

Comment: @Jai, Fermat for $p=11$ and $10=2+2\cdot 6 $.